# Pandas: Transform with custom maximum function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, transform

I know that I can use transform for transforming every element in a group in a dataframe into the minimum value.
This is done with something like

```
df.groupby(level=0).transform('min')
```

My problem is, that all of my cells are strings, in fact tuplelike strings with floats inside, like "5.48$\pm$69.1".
The minimum function here would transform it by string, which is incorrect.

Is there a good way of using a custom transform function only dealing with the first part of it?

An example input is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0.001': {('Periodic', 'Klinger'): '0.3$\\pm$0.05',
  ('Periodic', 'Malte'): '0.26$\\pm$0.06',
  ('Periodic', 'Merkelig'): '0.22$\\pm$0.12',
  ('Periodic', 'Dings'): '0.18$\\pm$0.06',
  ('Periodic', 'Elf'): '0.28$\\pm$0.11',
  ('Periodic', 'Rar'): '0.2$\\pm$0.1',
  ('Periodic', 'Merd'): '0.12$\\pm$0.14',
  ('Sequential', 'Klinger'): '0.15$\\pm$0.14',
  ('Sequential', 'Malte'): '0.1$\\pm$0.1',
  ('Sequential', 'Merkelig'): '0.26$\\pm$0.09',
  ('Sequential', 'Dings'): '0.17$\\pm$0.16',
  ('Sequential', 'Elf'): '0.15$\\pm$0.12',
  ('Sequential', 'Rar'): '0.12$\\pm$0.1',
  ('Sequential', 'Merd'): '0.21$\\pm$0.13'},
 '0.01': {('Periodic', 'Klinger'): '1.75$\\pm$1.27',
  ('Periodic', 'Malte'): '1.19$\\pm$1.51',
  ('Periodic', 'Merkelig'): '2.31$\\pm$0.54',
  ('Periodic', 'Dings'): '2.47$\\pm$0.37',
  ('Periodic', 'Elf'): '2.3$\\pm$1.3',
  ('Periodic', 'Rar'): '1.65$\\pm$0.59',
  ('Periodic', 'Merd'): '1.07$\\pm$1.68',
  ('Sequential', 'Klinger'): '1.14$\\pm$0.25',
  ('Sequential', 'Malte'): '2.99$\\pm$1.36',
  ('Sequential', 'Merkelig'): '2.85$\\pm$1.06',
  ('Sequential', 'Dings'): '2.61$\\pm$0.79',
  ('Sequential', 'Elf'): '1.62$\\pm$1.47',
  ('Sequential', 'Rar'): '1.29$\\pm$0.74',
  ('Sequential', 'Merd'): '2.88$\\pm$0.89'},
 '0.1': {('Periodic', 'Klinger'): '18.75$\\pm$12.96',
  ('Periodic', 'Malte'): '15.9$\\pm$9.8',
  ('Periodic', 'Merkelig'): '36.47$\\pm$1.42',
  ('Periodic', 'Dings'): '16.13$\\pm$13.24',
  ('Periodic', 'Elf'): '26.36$\\pm$11.08',
  ('Periodic', 'Rar'): '11.26$\\pm$12.32',
  ('Periodic', 'Merd'): '17.55$\\pm$10.78',
  ('Sequential', 'Klinger'): '36.26$\\pm$3.19',
  ('Sequential', 'Malte'): '20.2$\\pm$14.42',
  ('Sequential', 'Merkelig'): '18.62$\\pm$15.79',
  ('Sequential', 'Dings'): '5.64$\\pm$7.28',
  ('Sequential', 'Elf'): '25.55$\\pm$12.74',
  ('Sequential', 'Rar'): '19.65$\\pm$16.98',
  ('Sequential', 'Merd'): '14.53$\\pm$2.54'}})
```

There are three columns, 0.1, 0.01 and 0.001.
There is a multiindex consisting of two values and I want the minimum values within every column for each multiindex-first-value.

Everything is done by

```
df.groupby(level=0).transform('min')
```

but the minimum function is wrong due to the format of the values

Comment: Can you add inpud data to question and expected ouput?

Comment: I would recommend doing the text preprocessing first, then doing the transform as you suggest in your question on float data

Comment: Is it possible to print an already existing dataframe into the pd.DataFrame({''}) format?

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, I transformed my dataframe over many commands, therefore I did not provide input :( But maybe this is possible, so I can add it

Comment: You can print it normally (if there are no spaces in any of the cells), or use .to_dict() on the df

Comment: Thank you. I changed my question and put in example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for values before `$`, convert to floats, so possible use `min`:

```
f = lambda x: x.str.extract('([\d\.]+)\$', expand=False).astype(float).min()
df = df.groupby(level=0).transform(f)
print (df)
                     0.001  0.01    0.1
Periodic   Klinger    0.12  1.07  11.26
           Malte      0.12  1.07  11.26
           Merkelig   0.12  1.07  11.26
           Dings      0.12  1.07  11.26
           Elf        0.12  1.07  11.26
           Rar        0.12  1.07  11.26
           Merd       0.12  1.07  11.26
Sequential Klinger    0.10  1.14   5.64
           Malte      0.10  1.14   5.64
           Merkelig   0.10  1.14   5.64
           Dings      0.10  1.14   5.64
           Elf        0.10  1.14   5.64
           Rar        0.10  1.14   5.64
           Merd       0.10  1.14   5.64
```

If need also original values is possible use [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) with `key` parameter for sortying by floats and then select first value by position:

```
f = lambda x: x.sort_values(key = lambda y: y.str.extract('([\d\.]+)\$', expand=False).astype(float)).iat[0]
df = df.groupby(level=0).transform(f)
print (df)
                             0.001           0.01              0.1
Periodic   Klinger   0.12$\pm$0.14  1.07$\pm$1.68  11.26$\pm$12.32
           Malte     0.12$\pm$0.14  1.07$\pm$1.68  11.26$\pm$12.32
           Merkelig  0.12$\pm$0.14  1.07$\pm$1.68  11.26$\pm$12.32
           Dings     0.12$\pm$0.14  1.07$\pm$1.68  11.26$\pm$12.32
           Elf       0.12$\pm$0.14  1.07$\pm$1.68  11.26$\pm$12.32
           Rar       0.12$\pm$0.14  1.07$\pm$1.68  11.26$\pm$12.32
           Merd      0.12$\pm$0.14  1.07$\pm$1.68  11.26$\pm$12.32
Sequential Klinger     0.1$\pm$0.1  1.14$\pm$0.25    5.64$\pm$7.28
           Malte       0.1$\pm$0.1  1.14$\pm$0.25    5.64$\pm$7.28
           Merkelig    0.1$\pm$0.1  1.14$\pm$0.25    5.64$\pm$7.28
           Dings       0.1$\pm$0.1  1.14$\pm$0.25    5.64$\pm$7.28
           Elf         0.1$\pm$0.1  1.14$\pm$0.25    5.64$\pm$7.28
           Rar         0.1$\pm$0.1  1.14$\pm$0.25    5.64$\pm$7.28
           Merd        0.1$\pm$0.1  1.14$\pm$0.25    5.64$\pm$7.28
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this any helpful for your use case ?

```
import re

def min_float(x):
    floats = [float(re.search(r'([\d\.]+)', val).group(1)) for val in x]
    return min(floats)

df.groupby(level=0).transform(min_float)
```